# php mysql перенос time() в timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, в бд использовал до этого момента time() для установления значения времени (к примеру дата добавление новости), возможно ли теперь конвертировать значение полей с временем, в timestamp формат mysql?

Comment: Я в таких случая переносил к себе на локалку. Потом простеньким php алгоритмом проходил и менял. Всё проверил и на продакшн.

Answer (score 1):

В `mysql` есть подходящая функция [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). Соответственно необходимо:

- добавить новое поле с типом `timestamp`
- записать в него значения, конвертируя их из имеющегося поля
- проверить корректность конвертации и удалить старое поле

Т.е. вот так:

```
mysql> create table migratetest (t int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into migratetest values (1234567890);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> alter table migratetest add column ts timestamp null default null;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from migratetest;
+------------+------+
| t          | ts   |
+------------+------+
| 1234567890 | NULL |
+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update migratetest set ts = from_unixtime(t) 
       where t is not null and ts is null;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from migratetest;
+------------+---------------------+
| t          | ts                  |
+------------+---------------------+
| 1234567890 | 2009-02-14 02:31:30 |
+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table migratetest drop column t;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.18 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Новое поле затем возможно переименовать в старое, но из-за смены формата у вас и приложение скорей всего изменялось и удобнее как раз оставить использовать с новым именем.

Если время миграции получается довольно большим и необходимо сохранить работоспособность приложения - то процедура несколько изменяется:

- после добавления нового поля код приложение обновляется таким образом, чтобы читать данные только из старого поля, а писать (и обновлять) - оба, и старое и новое одновременно. Либо для этого можно создать пару триггеров: на `before insert` и `before update`
- после этого `update` модифицируется чтобы обновлять данные небольшими порциями, например по дополнительному условию `id >= 1000 and id < 2000`
- когда все строки обновлены, то приложение обновляется ещё раз с тем чтобы использовать только новое поле
- затем старое поле можно удалять

А вот как в mysql добавлять и удалять поля без длительной блокировки таблицы - уже достойно отдельного вопроса